# boost_thread not found , illumina bcl2fastq 1.8.3 installation error , casava ,illumina casava also showing same error

Tags: 14.04, cmake, boost

I am trying to install illumina bcl2fastq 1.8.3, on ubuntu 14.04, cmake is 2.8.4 and boost is 1.44. Both cmake and boost are bundled with bcl2fastq only.

I get the following error, can anyone please explain me this error, I couldn't understand it. Please also explain how to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.

```
CMake Error at /tmp/bcl2fastq_v1.8.3-build/bootstrap/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1128 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.44.0

  Boost include path: /tmp/bcl2fastq_v1.8.3-build/opt/bootstrap/include

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_thread

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/macros.cmake:93 (find_package)
  cmake/cxxConfigure.cmake:87 (casava_find_boost)
  c++/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so 
-- using compiler: gcc version 4.9.1
-- Adding the c++    library subdirectory: common
-- Adding the c++    library subdirectory: io
-- Adding the c++    library subdirectory: alignment
-- Adding the c++    library subdirectory: basecalling
-- Adding the c++    library subdirectory: kagu
-- Adding the c++    library subdirectory: demultiplex
-- Adding the c++    program subdirectory: bin
-- Adding the c++    program subdirectory: BaseCalls
-- Adding the c++    program subdirectory: Demultiplex
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen 
-- Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen. Dot: /usr/bin/dot.
-- Creating Doxygen config file: /tmp/bcl2fastq_v1.8.3-build/c++/Doxyfile
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Couldn't configure the project:

/tmp/bcl2fastq_v1.8.3-build/bootstrap/bin/cmake -H"/tmp/BclToFastq/src" -B"/tmp/bcl2fastq_v1.8.3-build" -G"Unix Makefiles"  -DCASAVA_PREFIX:PATH= -DCASAVA_EXEC_PREFIX:PATH= -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH= -DCASAVA_BINDIR:PATH= -DCASAVA_LIBDIR:PATH= -DCASAVA_LIBEXECDIR:PATH= -DCASAVA_INCLUDEDIR:PATH= -DCASAVA_DATADIR:PATH= -DCASAVA_DOCDIR:PATH= -DCASAVA_MANDIR:PATH= -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo

Moving CMakeCache.txt to CMakeCache.txt.removed
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! When you paste things from the terminal into the question or answer box, please select it all and press `Ctrl + K`, it makes it easier to read. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Bcl2Fastq source code does not compile on Ubuntu 14.04. Here are alternative instructions for running the RPM binary on 14.04 [(source)](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showpost.php?p=141026&postcount=29):

```
sudo alien -i bcl2fastq-1.8.4-Linux-x86_64.rpm
sudo apt-get install build-essential
curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
echo >> ~/.bash_profile "source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc"
perlbrew install perl-5.14.4
perlbrew switch perl-5.14.4
perlbrew install-cpanm
cpanm XML/Simple.pm
```

Note:

- Run as a non-root user.
- Installing (build) process took about 10min for my environment.
- You can also use "aptitude" instead of "apt-get".
- For perlbrew, you can use "use" instead of "switch" to set-up only for current shell.
  You may need to install other required modules using cpanm.

Comment: @ bain I think wat u said is quite correct , i tried to install bcl2fastq 1.8.3 on 14.04 LTS , after going through many error logs and browsing stuff , i am doubting the same ,

Comment: @ bain , hi , Could you please explain me how a rpm files of 1.8.4 works with 14.04 ubuntu where 1.8.3 tar files fails

Comment: @RajYadav RPM files contain pre-compiled binaries. Tar files contain source code that you need to compile.

Comment: Download http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.14.4.tar.bz2 to /home/vanessa/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.14.4.tar.bz2
Installing /home/vanessa/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.14.4 into ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.4

This could take a while. You can run the following command on another shell to track the status:

  tail -f ~/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.14.4.log
../ext/re/t/reflags.t ............................................. ok
../ext/re/t/regop.t ............................................... ok
../lib/AnyDBM_File.t .............................................. ok

Comment: @ bain , hi bain thanks for the clue , please see the comment above,from there the process is not moving forward , i waited nearly 12 hrs still of no use , do u have any idea about this

Comment: Can you please post this as a separate question "Problem installing perl with perlbrew"? It is very difficult to see from the comment formatting exactly what you did and what the error was.